# Duah vs. Dua? Which one is right?

Tags: phrases, exclamations

For the phrase, "Yeah, duah [dua]," which spelling is correct? In this case "duah," means "obviously."

Comment: Neither? I've seen it spelled [*duh.*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duh) And Homer Simpson spells it [*d'oh*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/d'oh) (and pronounces it slightly differently).

Comment: @PeterShor *D'oh* is spelled *annoyed grunt*. ;-)

Comment: "Duh" is the usual spelling.

Comment: @PeterShor I've always understood 'd'oh' to have a different meaning than 'duh', namely something closer to 'uh oh'.

Comment: @Mitch: I've always considered Homer's *d'oh* a variant of *duh* meaning: *"how could I have been so stupid"*. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor Both interjections are in the dictionary. They are similar but not considered synonyms (they work in different contexts). To oversimplify, 'duh' is for being stupid, 'd'oh' is for something bad that has or is going to happen.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you want the word *duh*. Neither *dua* nor *duah* appears in the dictionaries I checked.